# Best Way to Handle the UI Layer Within a Ruby Architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface

Are there some tools like CMS or UI-level frameworks that help in the maintenance and development of the UI layer within Ruby architectures?

I am still learning Ruby but as I understand it, it is very coupled with the front-end, correct?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use active_scaffold to get ajaxified crud interface and it can get integrated inside your existing rails app easily.

[github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Getting-Started](http://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Getting-Started)

You can also use hobo but from I have gathered you need to use it right from the beginning as its generator creates the app.

[hobocentral.net/](http://hobocentral.net/)

You can use comatose cms for integrating a basic content management functionality in your existing ror app.

[comatose.rubyforge.org/getting-started-01.html](http://comatose.rubyforge.org/getting-started-01.html)

Also if you are looking for something pre-packed with rails then you can use command:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

Command above is specific for rails 3 (in previous version scaffolding was available via ruby script/generate scaffold).

[guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah this helps.  It gave me ideas on what to do in regard to a number of questions I had - thanks!

Comment: you can create links using ctrl-l

Comment: @MByD: I had to add links as text cause it would not allow me to add more than two links as I have recently started in the community. Thanks for turning them into links.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there some tools like CMS or UI-level frameworks that help in the maintenance and development of the UI layer within Ruby architectures?

CMS and UI level frameworks are very broad categories that you are talking about. Just to get you started, I will list down some I started with

1. [Nifty-generators](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators)
2. [blueprint-css](https://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css)
3. [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails)

> I am still learning Ruby but as I understand it, it is very coupled with the front-end, correct?

No, its not very coupled with the front end as you think it is. You can assume Rails(Ruby) as just the back-end that will just send back data and when data has arrived at front-end, its your wish how to present it, format it or whatever you want to do with it.